# For a given blog overflow blog post, (tastefully) automagically show related and interesting questions?

Tags: feature-request, site-promotion, blog-overflow

I often share blogoverflow posts on facebook to people who have no concept of what SE is. My friends go and checkout that blog post and say "hey that article was really cool"!. Interesting discussion ensues. My friends may be interested and passionate about the subject -- just the type of person to recruit to that site! But since they have no idea that SE exists, they may need some more mind-porn to draw them into even more interesting content.

To entice their curiosity even more, what if we showed a list of highly voted related questions on that blog post -- similar to how we automagically show similar/related questions to other SE questions. So for this great [fitness blogoverflow post](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/10/if-i-can-run-so-can-you/). We could possibly detect and show a few related questions maybe in the following format:

If you're interested in more, see also:

- [What can I use to monitor my running workout?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-can-i-use-to-monitor-my-running-workout)
- [Is there a rule of thumb for setting running goals?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/53/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-setting-running-goals)

(forgive my lame attempt at manually finding related questions)

The blog author could also be given this list when writing their blog post and given a chance to edit or make changes to it.

Comment: Is there a particular place in the UI you think this should go?

Comment: @Grace I'm not sure, it could be a side bar thing or maybe at the bottom? I don't know what would be best without being annoying or spammy... I'd be interested in what other people thought.

Comment: Side bar like on SE sites sounds best to me.